# EF savechanges() does not effect on my .mdf DB

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, mdf

I have this model on my .mdf DB:

[image]

these 2 tables with no data:

[image]

PersonID is a foreign key.

This is my EF model diagram:

[image]

And this is the code for adding a person.

```
    namespace DBTest
{
    class Class1
    {
        MyDBEntities db;
        public Class1()
        {
            db = new MyDBEntities();
            AddPerson();
        }        


        void AddPerson()
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.ID=1;
            p.NAME="abcd";
            db.AddToPerson(p);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

After I call to the class from the main:

```
    namespace DBTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 a = new Class1();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to see if there's any change in my .mdf DB.
I find that the database is still empty (after refreshing):

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I need to do to cause the database to be updated?
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBTest.Properties.Settings.XXXXConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\XXXX.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Hyave you found solution for this problem? I've done database in VS and having same problem as you described. Can you explain how you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show us your **connection string** - but I'm just guessing from the "symptoms" you report.

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDB`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...